# How to Clear Screen in TASM?

Tags: assembly, tasm

I just want to ask how to clear screen in TASM?.

For example, I run my program, how to delete all the contents then print the output?.

Hope you understand my explanation.

Thank You =}

Answer (score 1):

This depends on the operating system!

MS-DOS: Use Interrupt 0x10 (see link in Devolus' comment)

MS-DOS with ansi.sys installed: Write ESC+"[2J" to the standard output

Windows: Call console functions

Linux: Write ESC+"[2J" to the standard output